# Help with rows in a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a problem. I have an app that allows you to right click on a row in the datagrid and a menu item pops up that lets you copy, move, or delete the row. When i click on one of these options, I get a nullReferenceException. When i step through, I am getting a null value on qv.Name. Anyone got any ideas? Also, let me know if you need more code. Thanks.

Comment: So qv itself is never null? Only the qv.Name property? If so I think the answer is that your Name property is not set...and not knowing your QuarantineView innards and how it interacts with the rest of the system not much else can be said...

Comment: That's quite a bit of nesting (including even a set of curly braces with no qualifying code block).  Might I suggest you reverse some of those conditionals to supply terminating/breaking conditions first to reduce the nesting?

Comment: Then your dgSystemView.SelectedItem is either null or not of type QuarantineView

Comment: Sounds like the row is not of type QuarantineView, can you post how you populate the DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, I think you want:

```
QuarantineViewDS.QuarantineViewRow qv = 
    dgSystemView.SelectedItem as QuarantineViewDS.QuarantineViewRow;
```

instead of:

```
QuarantineView qv = dgSystemView.SelectedItem as QuarantineView;
```

Comment: Then I'm thinking that `dgSystemView.SelectedItem` is null

Comment: Yeah, it looks like by clicking on the row it might be 'deselecting' the row, so the `SelectedItem` would be null.  See this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532485/right-click-on-grid-row

Comment: What is the type of `qvDS.QuarantineView.DefaultView`? Is it a list of something?

Comment: Yeah, from the original post.  What is (`dgSystemView.DataContext = qvDS.QuarantineView.DefaultView;`) the type of `DefaultView`?

Comment: Then converting it to a `DataRowView` should work: `DataRowView qv = dgSystemView.SelectedItem as DataRowView;`

Comment: Is it possible to change your `DefaultView` from a `DataView` to a `ObservableCollection<QuarantineViewRow>`.  Then I think you could do your direct cast to a `QuarantineViewRow`.  I'm not sure how to convert the `DataRowView` to the `QuarantineViewRow`.